# AS3 laser weapon

Tags: actionscript-3

I am pretty new to action script 3 (I did a little bit in as2) and i am trying to create a laser gun that rotates towards the mouse and shoots when the mouse is fired.

kind of like this but in as3

http://www.freeactionscript.com/2009/04/laser-hitting-solid-objects-walls/

Thanks,
Thor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start to play with something like this:

```
//adding listener to run all the time
m.addEventListener("enterFrame", runGame);
//listener for mouse is down
stage.addEventListener("mouseDown", md);
//listener for mouse is up
stage.addEventListener("mouseUp", mu);

//to know if mouse is down
var _fire:Boolean = false;

//function for all the time
function runGame(evt:*):void
{
    //to know the angle where the mouse is from the "canon" in radians
    var angle:Number = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - m.y, stage.mouseX - m.x);

    //set the canon's rotation
    m.rotation = 180 * angle / Math.PI;

    //if mouse us down -> fire
    if(_fire)
    {
        //create a point far away, so it will always work if the screen is normal
        var point:Point = Point.polar(10000, angle);

        //shoot the laser
        graphics.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    }
}

//when mouse is down
function md(evt:*):void
{
    //prepare graphics
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
    graphics.moveTo(m.x, m.y);

    //set fire to true
    _fire = true;
}

//when mouse is up
function mu(evt:*):void
{
    //set fire to false
    _fire = false;

    //clear the laser
    graphics.clear();
}
```

Create a new project, place a movieclip on the stage, name it "m" (without the quotes ;)). Paste the script where the actionscript goes on frame 1.

If you want the laser to follow the mouse when it's down, change

runGame function to this:

```
function runGame(evt:*):void
{
    //to know the angle where the mouse is from the "canon" in radians
    var angle:Number = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - m.y, stage.mouseX - m.x);

    //set the canon's rotation
    m.rotation = 180 * angle / Math.PI;

    //if mouse us down -> fire
    if(_fire)
    {
        //create a point far away, so it will always work if the screen is normal
        var point:Point = Point.polar(10000, angle);

        //shoot the laser
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
        graphics.moveTo(m.x, m.y);
        graphics.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    }
}
```

and md function to this:

```
//when mouse is down
function md(evt:*):void
{
    //set fire to true
    _fire = true;
}
```

Comment: ok worked perfectly fine until i added it to another movieclip called dracoplay. it started shooting from a corner

Comment: Did you change every "m." to "dracoplay." in the code? Is the new movieclip on the same layer as "m" was? Which corner did it start to shoot from?

Answer (score 0):

["Epic" laser](http://wonderfl.net/c/zFPG), with source. Also great site btw.

Comment: couldn't figure out how to do this :(<

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to learn the basic concepts of programming before trying to tackle things like this. Cutting/Pasting code is not programming, and can have frankenstein-ish results.

There is no magical shortcut to programming, you need to learn the basic concepts and build on them. Wonderfl.net is a cool place to check out, but I'd suggest starting out far more basic concepts to start. Until you do that, it's all going to appear as voodoo to you.

Comment: Well i am kind of familiar with it so the basics like listeners, functions,variables i kind of get that stuff but i find the best way to learn is find code take it apart and see what each part does and then make it better